# catchError failed to handle the thrown error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to catch error from service that returns coordinates and return default if error occurs, but it does not work. Default coordinates are not returned. It doesn't even go to subscribe line.

```
this.coordinateService
      .getMyCoordinates()
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return of(new GeoCoordinates(0, 0));
        })
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.initMap(data);
      });
```

service:

```
getMyCoordinates(): Observable<GeoCoordinates> {
    throw new Error("Coordinates not found");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return Observable from your `getMyCoordinates()`

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/throwError';

getMyCoordinates(): Observable<GeoCoordinates> {
      return throwError("Coordinates not found");
}
```